# Codeigniter Application Deployement on live server

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to deploy my application on live server its working fine on local server but on live server I am getting the error message :"The requested document was not found on this server." here is the necessary configurations mentioned may help to answer. I can access my CSS & JS placed outside application folders but not redirecting to my controller/method/view. Please advice

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mydomain.org';
```

**database.php**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mydomain.org';
$db['default']['username'] = 'myuser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypwd';
$db['default']['database'] = 'myDB';
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/user/login";
on my localhost
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome"; is also working fine
```

**.HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cicms

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In .htaccess file change RewriteBase /cicms to RewriteBase / if the website is on root of server, i.e. not in sub folder...

Comment: yes website is on the root of the server i.e httpdocs/mywebsite and I changed the RewriteBase/cicms to RewriteBase / its not working yet. I am using codeigniter framework I've another site placed under root directory but its simple PHP site and thats working

Comment: Then In .htaccess file change RewriteBase /cicms to RewriteBase /

Comment: I did the same as I mentioned earlier

Comment: Try to Make debug mode on and then check.. may it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Make a index.php file beside your welcome.php file and put your codes, functions there and make it your default controller. The CI engine doesn't read files inside folder as its default_controller. Once try this. It once helped me....

and make your .htaccess Rewritebase /smthng as Rewritebase /

Comment: I dont't want to use Index.php in my URL's I am using this url to access my pages and getting the error message
http://mydomain.org/cicms/admin/user/login and the error is Requested document not found on server

Comment: Could you please provide me the settings for Codeigniter Application to deploy on live server
specially
$config['base_url']
considering my folder structure
htdocs/CICM/admin/user/login
where CICM is my website folder, admin is subfolder, user is controller, login is view
$route[] what should be default route
also the .htaccess file

Comment: You don't need to use index.php in your urls. just avoid capital letters for your folders and file name.coz php server is mainly linux based and linux is case sensitive.... to remove index.php edit your htaccess as you have done already. and just redirect your default controller to index.php as I said above... and you don't need to use index.php in your urls... and remove index.php from $config['index_page'] =""; from config file.. Thats all you need to do